# Move agent based on probability/point attribute value and point distance, NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I have the set of points implemented in netlogo and agents are moving from one point to another. Each point has a weight (number approximately between 0 and 9, its not a probability). What I want to made is a simple rule.
I want to give all points probability of visit by the value of weight.
So the next point which will be visited by agent should be calculated by the probability based on point weight and the closeness point (more close point - bigger probability), but that closeness isn't so much big factor as the point weight. For example, I would like to set in formula  that closeness is twice lower factor then point weight.

I investigated rnd extension, but I am not sure how to append probabilities to points which I am having a lot (approximately around 250 points).

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track with the `rnd` extension. From that extension you need the `weighted-one-of` primitive and you just put the formula into the reporter block.

I think this is something like what you want. It's a complete model so you can run it and see what it does. The reporter block uses the weight and the distance in the probability. Since you want the probability to be larger for closer, then I have used the inverse of the distance, but you could simply subtract the distance from something like the maximum distance in the model. You will also need an appropriate scaling factor (replacing the 10 in my example) so that the weight is worth twice an average value of closeness.

```
extensions [rnd]

turtles-own [weight]

to testme
  clear-all
  create-turtles 10
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set weight 1 + random 3
    set size weight
    set color blue
  ]
  ask one-of turtles
  [ set color red
    let target rnd:weighted-one-of other turtles [ 2 * weight + 10 / distance myself ]
    ask target [ set color yellow ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thank you JenB. In my case weight is a feature/attribute of the points in shapefile and my agents are moving between those points. That's the part that confuses me, i am not that familiar with gis extension.. And there is only 2 examples in netlogo library.

Comment: Standard advice - don't try and solve the whole thing at once. Get your GIS file imported and have the agents randomly select one of the points. Once that is solved, you can worry about selecting using a more complicated relationship. You will never be able to debug if you introduce multiple elements of the model at the same time.

Comment: I already done that, now I just need the rule, in order not to walk randomly from point to point. :D

Comment: Then I don't understand your initial comment that you can't make it work with GIS. My answer shows you how to use a rule with weighting that includes both an attribute owned by the turtle and the distance to the other turtle.

Comment: That's the problem. That attribute in my model isn't owned by turtle. Its a feature of point in shapefile data. And I need distance to the other points, not turtles. I don't know how to use "data/column weight" from the shapefile and to with rng extension add probability to it, base on the value of weight. And then to tell the turtles to look distance between them and point and that probability of point.

Comment: Then you need to create a new question and ask about getting GIS information into NetLogo - wherever it is you are getting stuck. Focus on that instead of all the apparently irrelevant information about random selection.